# Rails 3.0 Model without Validation does not get saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Looks like I messed up my code in a very subtle way... suddenly one of my models doesn't save anymore.

First thing I tried was to see if the same commands work in the Rails console, and to my surprise it showed the record(s) not being valid.

To narrow-down the problem, I commented-out all validations and tried again -- but it still did not work!

```
m = MyModel.find 123
 => record which looks OK to me
m.valid?
 => false
m.errors
 => #<OrderedHash {}>    # An EMPTY hash??? Is that a Rails bug?
```

Has anybody seen something like this before?

Comment: Can you try using `save!` instead of `save` method? It usually displays explicit console error that displays which validation failed.

Comment: Thanks, I found it. I should just RTFM :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Apparently one of my before_validation methods returned false - ugh - stupid mistake!!

Here's what the ActiveRecord documentation has to say on that topic:

**before_validation* returning statements**

If the returning value of a before_validation callback can be evaluated to false, the process will be aborted and Base#save will return false. If ActiveRecord::Validations#save! is called it will raise a ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception. Nothing will be appended to the errors object.

Yeah, it works as advertised!! :)

See also: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html